# Does HDF do string interning?

Tags: hdf5

Just wondering how liberal I can be with group/dataset names or if I need to make the names short (and hence less readable).  This would be for a HDF5 file that contains many groups and datasets that would have many duplicate names. Some XML APIs do [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) as an optimization and it would make sense for HDF to do this but I can't tell from the online documentation if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not explicitly. The HDF5 file format does not specify any compression for the object headers (where the group and dataset names are stored). The actual writing to disk is handled through one of several [low-level file drivers](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/08_TheFile.html#Drivers). I don't know if any of these do string interning, but it is possible to write your own file driver which does. The [technical notes](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/TechNotes/VFL.html) on the virtual file layer may be of some help if you need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Although the HDF5 library does not provide string interning for link names in a group, with version 1.8.x of the HDF5 library, the heap containing link names for each group can be compressed, using the H5Pset_filter() call, passing in a "group creation property list" (GCPL), which is then passed to the call to create the group.  Note that the file creation property list (FCPL) is a sub-class of group creation property lists and can be passed to H5Pset_filter to allow the root group's heap to be compressed.

See: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetFilter

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's reliable to put whatever string you want to as a group or dataset name in HDF5. For example (from Python)

```
import h5py

h5file = h5py.File("newfile.h5", "w")
h5file.create_group("an incredibly descriptive, maybe even obnoxious group name")

h5grp  = h5file["an incredibly descriptive, maybe even obnoxious group name"]
h5dset = h5grp.create_dataset("all kinds of useful things", [100,100])

print h5dset

h5file.close()
```

Alternatively, you may want to use cruder group and dataset names, along with a verbose string-valued attribute to explain the meaning of the data.

Comment: This does not answer the question.